# On ubuntu add a HD to RAID5 but the size do not Extension

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid

In this time I have a RAID5 using three HDs(2TB*3) and I was tinking to Add a new HD and Extension the size to 6TB,

The existing HDs is [adb][adc][add]=[md0]
Then add HD is [sde]

Wat I did is,,,

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sde
```

With this [sde] came to "spare",
Next I did to change the RAID5 constitution three to four,

```
# mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-disks=4
```

The result was like this,

```
# mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Thu Jan  7 11:03:24 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5860543488 (5589.05 GiB 6001.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953514496 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan 11 13:33:51 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : 6d0b323f:b75aaec0:bb0d87a8:14c047e2 (local to host SIGMA-N)
         Events : 0.12206

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
```

After this I mout the [md0]
But the problem was after this,
Even I use the  **df -h** or see the mount area from Windows the size did not Change,
I Reboot and type a few command like this,

```
# mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

But it did not make a difflents, I hope If some body can teach about this problem.

Comment: Hallo,
I found the solution.<br>
The FileSystem was XFS so I used  this commond<br>

<pre># xfs_growfs </pre><br>

And now all is it good.<br>
Thank you!